# Java app crashes (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i'm just programming a password manager but every time I run it, it crashed in cause of NullPointerException. I checked the code but i'm a new developer. Someone here who knows why? :(

Code of MainActivity.java:

```
package de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button login;
EditText masterpassfield;
static String masterpass;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    masterpass = "";
    masterpassfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masterpass);

    if(masterpass.equals("")) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewMasterpass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(masterpassfield.getText().toString().equals(masterpass)) {

                Intent success = new Intent(view.getContext(), Passwords.class);
                startActivityForResult(success, 0);

            }

        }});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Code of NewMasterpass.java:

```
package de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewMasterpass extends Activity {

EditText masterpasscreate;
EditText repeat;
Button finish;
TextView mistake;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_masterpass);

    masterpasscreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masterpasscreate);
    repeat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.repeatcreate);
    finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);
    mistake = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mistake);

    finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(!masterpasscreate.getText().toString().equals(repeat.getText().toString())) {

                mistake.setText("The passwords are different.");
                mistake.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            else if(masterpasscreate.getText().toString().equals("") || repeat.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                mistake.setText("Both textfields must be filled in");
                mistake.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            else {

                MainActivity.masterpass = masterpasscreate.getText().toString();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        }});


}
}
```

LogCat error:

```
01-20 17:17:52.629: D/AndroidRuntime(561): Shutting down VM
01-20 17:17:52.629: W/dalvikvm(561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x409961f8)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivit    y}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-20 17:17:52.639: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  ... 11 more
01-20 17:17:57.129: I/Process(561): Sending signal. PID: 561 SIG: 9
01-20 17:21:37.499: D/AndroidRuntime(608): Shutting down VM
01-20 17:21:37.499: W/dalvikvm(608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-20 17:21:37.511: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  ... 11 more
01-20 17:22:30.769: D/AndroidRuntime(655): Shutting down VM
01-20 17:22:30.769: W/dalvikvm(655): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655):  ... 11 more
01-20 17:22:33.180: I/Process(655): Sending signal. PID: 655 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the full error from logcat.  It tells you the exact line the problem happened on.

Comment: You need to look at the exception to work out where it occurred. It should show you the exact line which has the problem. Learning to understand stack traces and diagnose errors for yourself is a very important skill for a developer.

Comment: The error couldn't be more clear I'd say :`Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `NewMasterPass` activity in your manifest xml as clearly mentioned in the logcat!

Answer (score 1):

It asks:

```
01-20 17:22:30.779: E/AndroidRuntime(655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager/de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass}; 

have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Have you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="de.lennartschoch.passwordmanager.NewMasterpass" />
```